# If insert statement gives duplicate key exception(row id=1 found in table) how to update the statement in JDBC(Postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, arraylist

I have Stored bunch of insert statements in ArrayList.like below

```
List<String> script=new ArrayList<String>;
script.add("INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Madhava'));
script.add(INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'Rao'));
script.add(INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES(1, 'Bangalore'))
script.add(INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES(2, 'Hyd'));
```

I created connection to the postgresql using jdbc i get executed statments using for loop like below

```
try{
        Connection con=DBConnections.getPostgresConnection();
         Statment statment=con.createStatment();
        for(String query:script){
           executeUpdate(query);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If i get duplication key exception(i.e.Already record exist in postgresDB).

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value 
  violates unique constraint "reports_uniqueness_index"
```

How to update the same statment(record) with update query into Postgres.
Is there any way to solve this ?
Is there any other better way to solve this?
Could you please explain...

Comment: You could use `insert on conflict ...`

Comment: The way to solve it would be to either UPDATE if a key exists or use an auto generated key.

Comment: Don't think you should have a List of INSERTs; better to have a List of objects that you pass to a PreparedStatement and execute against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Execute update sends a DML statement over to the database. Your database must already have a record which uses one of the primary keys either in the employees or address table.

You have to ensure you don't violate the primary key constraint. Violating the constraint is resulting in the exception.

Either change your query to an update statement, or delete the records which are causing conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the key that caused the exception (though you can probably parse the error message, which is certainly not recommended).

Instead, you should try preventing this from ever happenning. There are at least 3 easy ways to accomplish this.

1. Make the database update the column

   ```
   (in Postgresql you should use a serial type (which is basically an int data type)
   CREATE TABLE employee
   (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    --other columns here )
   ```

Your insert will now look like

```
   script.add("INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(NAME) VALUES ('Madhava'));//no ID here
```

2. Create a sequence and have your JDBC code call the sequence' nexval method.

   ```
   script.add("INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES (YOUR_SEQ_NAME.NEXTVAL(), 'Madhava'));
   ```
3. Create a unique ID in Java (least recommended)

   ```
   script.add("INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES (UUID.random(), 'Madhava'));//or Math.random() etc
   ```